# Defining a function of a function defined with Map

Tags: function-construction

Context: just exploring activation functions in neural networks, particularly the new SWISH function defined in [this arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.05941.pdf)

It's a simple function of two variables, x & beta

```
swish[\[Beta]_, x_] := x/(1 + Exp[-\[Beta] x])
```

[I may post a separate question concerning my similar inability to define a derivative function for this - pro tem I had MMA evaluate the derivative and re-entered for the formula by hand]

I then define a function to apply it element-wise to a matrix (list) $M$ as

```
swishMatrix[\[Beta]_, M_] := swish[\[Beta], #] & /@ M
```

which works as expected for this

```
In[204]:= swishMatrix[0.5, Range[-10, 10]]

Out[204]= {-0.0669285, -0.0988825, -0.14389, -0.205186, -0.284555, \
-0.379291, -0.476812, -0.547277, -0.537883, -0.377541, 0., 0.622459, \
1.46212, 2.45272, 3.52319, 4.62071, 5.71544, 6.79481, 7.85611, \
8.90112, 9.93307}
```

But what I want to do is define another function that will accept the range specification as a parameter (with additional range increment) thus

```
a[\[Beta]_, x_, inc_] := swishMatrix[\[Beta], Range[-x, x, inc]];
```

But I get the error

```
SetDelayed::write: Tag List in {-0.284555,-0.307069,-0.330477,-0.35462,<<41>>,4.89538,5.16952,5.44293,5.71544}[\[Beta]_,x_,inc_] is Protected.
```

I thought (but not knowing what I was doing) that maybe I should "Hold" something, but nothing I tried helped [nonsensical examples omitted].

Question: How should I redefine **swish** or **a** - and more than that, why? I thought MMA didn't evaluate things until it needed to so I really don't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: use `ClearAll[a]` before defining `a`.

Comment: @kglr OK, thanks! No more SetDelayed error, but why? What needed to be cleared and why did it cause that particular error?

Comment: Julian, somewhere/sometime  **before** using  `a[\[Beta]_, x_, inc_] := ...` in your mathematica session, you have defined `a` as a list (`{-0.284555,-0.307069,-0.330477,-0.35462,....}`) . You need to `Clear` or `ClearAll` symbol `a` before you  assign new values to it.

Comment: @kgl You must be right - but not "explicitly" - probably while trying different ways of defining "a" as immediate rather than delayed. Just did a test - I see -sort of. But if I define e.g. bbb = {1,2,3} and check Head it is a List, if I immediately redefine it as bbb=2 it is Integer, so heads can change, why doesn't definining bbb[x_]:=x^2 just overwrite (to have Head "Symbol". why can the head change in some ways but not others... Curious!

Answer (score 1):

When you assign to `a[...]` you are not changing the head; you are creating a rule.  So if `a={1,2,3}` and you attempt to assign say `a[1]=2`, then `a` is evaluated to `{1,2,3}`, so your are really trying to assign `{1,2,3}[1]=2`, which is impossible. (One can only associate values with symbols, not with values.)